# C# Convert T to long

Tags: c#, generics, types, int

I have a generic class (C#),

```
class MyClass<T> where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    public T filelocation;
}
```

T can be either UInt32 or UInt64 (nothing else).

I need to convert filelocation to a long to seek in a file...

I have tried the following

```
long loc = (T)myclass.filelocation;

long loc = (T)(object)myclass.filelocation;
```

But nothing seems to work...

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have a generic class/method that only takes uint or ulong then you are probably abusing or misusing generics. Generics are supposed to be *generic*. Why not just have a non-generic class that takes a ulong? The uint will be converted to ulong automatically.

Comment: I'm working with the PST file format.  It has two formats, ANSI (UInt32) and UNICODE (UInt64).  I'm doing it this way to (hopefully) reduce code duplication

Comment: @Eric: I went your route.  I rewrote it to not be generic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Call `Convert.ToInt64`.

Writing `(object)fileLocation` creates a boxed `UInt32`.
[Boxed value types can only be unboxed to their original value types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx), so you cannot cast it in one step to `long`.
You could write `(long)(ulong)fileLocation`, but that will fail for a `uint` for the same reason.

Comment: Also for this the class should have a `IConvertible` constraint

Comment: @Broken: No; `Convert.ToInt64` takes an `object`.  However, you're right; it ought to have that constraint.

Comment: I ended up rewriting everything to not be generic.  Since T could only be one of two values, I put some if statements in there, where it mattered...  But this was the route I was going before I rewrote.

Answer (score 1):

You may use TryParse:

```
long lng;
int testNum = 55;
long.TryParse(testNum.ToString(),out lng);
```

Comment: [`long.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h.aspx) requires a string as input parameter, not a `UInt32` or `UInt64`, i.e. it won't compile!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Convert.ToInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint64.aspx).

```
long loc = Convert.ToInt64(myclass.filelocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

with your class definition if i write something like

```
public MyClass<long> myclass = new MyClass<long>();
    public long returnLong() 
            {
                return myclass.filelocation;
            }
```

myclass.fileLocation return long by defult